# Testing sequence for type of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Test the sequence $x_n=2^{-n}$ for different types of convergence (linear, superlinear, or quadratic), where $n=1,2,3,...$

I have no idea how to test for the different types of convergence. Is there a method for testing each one? Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know what those terms meant, but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence), you just need to find some various limits as prescribed by the definitions. For the first two: Let $L$ be the limit of $x_n$, then we need to find:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - L|}{|x_n - L|} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{-(n+1)}}{2^{-n}} = \,?$$
If the limit exists, it converges linearly. If the limit is zero, convergence is superlinear. You can take a look at wikipedia for the quadratic case.